# Anime about a boy who made a deal with a demon underground

Tags: story-identification, anime, demons

All I can remember about it the story was fantasy about a boy who made a deal with a demon underground, I think, but she transformed into something else because he made the creature angry. He also wanted to marry the emperor's daughter who was with him, but the emperor would not let him. The employer was also holding a dragon in a fenced-in barrier. The princess talked to it and got its power. The emperor's head of security was this little boy.

Can't remember much more hope you can figure it out.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, did the story take place in a medieval setting?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.